# Is there a limit for how many layers can be put into a group?

Tags: qgis

I am Running QGIS Lisboa 1.8.0 on a MacBook Pro. I have several vector layers with similar information which clutter the Layers panel.  I created a group to put them in but when I drag and drop the layers into the new group I get just so many into the new group and then the layers panel becomes unstable. I can start to drag another layer and the new group disappears. QGIS then exits generating a large error report.
I am using the method given in the manual for QGIS 1.7.0 and it appears to work up to the point where it all goes wrong.

Is this a known problem with this version of QGIS? I havent been able to find a reference to this particular problem.

Nigel

Comment: At what count is the tiping point?

Comment: I can get 8 layers in to the new group. When I try to drag the last layer in the new group disappears and I get an error message std::bad-alloc with an OK option. At this point the new group and the last layer have disappeared from the layers pane. When I click OK I get the spinning rainbow of death and QGIS quits and a very large 'problem Report is generated. I saved the project with the new group with the eight layers in it before I tried to drag the last layer in. Now when I reopen the project the new group and contents is no longer in the layers pane.

Comment: I could not reproduce the error on Windows XP, Qgis 1.8.0 and master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a bug. There are already a few known similar cases, but you describe something new, so please report it on the [bugtracker](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues) (include the generated report). For reference, the most similar existing reported issue [is this one](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/5932).

Comment: I have tried to re-create the original problem but without success. I can't get QGIS to crash.  I did manage to create a new group and drag and drop the new layers to it as I created them. However when I save the project, quit QGIS and then reopened QGIS and the project, the previously created group and it's contents were not there.  I will tru again to re-create the problem and report back.

Comment: OK, tried again. Still can't get QGIS to crash. Re-imported all 8 new vector layers. Created new group and dragged new layers into it. Added some labelling to a couple of the layers (as I had in original scenario). Saved the project, quit QGIS and restarted again. Opened project and all the data is there.  There is something more subtle going on here but I can't get to it :(  Good that QGIS is performing as it should but annoying that intermittent problem exists.